# Why do you need higher kinds?

Tags: programming-languages, type-systems, generics

Some languages allow for classes and functions with type parameters (such as `List<T>` where `T` may be an arbitrary type). For example, you can have a function like:

```
List<S> Function<S, T>(List<T> list)
```

Some languages however allow this concept to be extended one level higher, allowing you to have a function with the signature:

```
K<S> Function<K<_>, S, T>(K<T> arg)
```

Where `K<_>` itself is a type like `List<_>` that has a type parameter. This "partial type" is known as a type constructor.

My question is, why do you need this ability? It makes sense to have a type like `List<T>` because all `List<T>` are almost exactly the same, but all the `K<_>` can be entirely different. You can have an `Option<_>` and a `List<_>` that have no common functionality at all.

Comment: There are several good answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21170493/when-are-higher-kinded-types-useful

Comment: @itsbruce In particular, the `Functor` example in Luis Casillas's answer is quite intuitive. What do `List<T>` and `Option<T>` have in common? If you give me either one and a function `T -> S` I can give you a `List<S>` or `Option<S>`. Another thing they have in common is that you can try to get a `T` value out of both.

Comment: @Doval: How would you do the former?  To the extent that one is interested in the latter, I would think that could be handled by having both types implement `IReadableHolder<T>`.

Comment: @supercat I'm guessing they would have to implement `IMappable<K<_>, T>` with the method `K<S> Map(Func<T, S> f)`, implementing as `IMappable<Option<_>, T>`, `IMappable<List<_>, T>`. So you would have to constrain `K<T> : IMappable<K<_>, T>` to get any use out of it.

Comment: @supercat You'd need something analogous to Haskell's type classes or (I'm guessing) Scala's traits so you could make use of the common functionality or provide it if it doesn't come built in. You could fake it in Java/C# by making parametrized interfaces (e.g. `Functor<T>`) that delegate to the implementation and passing them as an argument to generic functions. But without higher kinds you'll still run into trouble, because when `T` is `List<String>` you'll lose the `String` part of the type. I.e. You can't write methods that take some `Functor<T<S>>` and makes use of the `S` type.

Comment: @supercat You are entirely missing the point. Type classes do not require a shared dependency.  They provide a way of arbitrarily placing one type into a larger group without any modification of the original type and with no need for type-specific code in the larger abstraction.  You're too close to the OO trees to see the more abstract forest.  Code written to work with a higher kinded type also has no dependency on the lower, more concrete types.

Comment: @itsbruce: I dislike the notion of "duck-typing by name" without using interfaces, since given two objects P and Q encapsulating {1,2} and {3,4}, the notion of "adding" Q to P is ambiguous: should it yield {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,{3,4}}, or {4,6}?  The ways interfaces work in Java and .NET are a bit limited, but I'm not clear how types could be regarded as "similar" except by either name-based duck-typing or by using some form of interface.

Comment: @supercat Type-classes are like interfaces, but you implement them outside of the type. Say, a type-class `Mult` requires a type `T` to have a function like `T multiply(int,T)`. Now you define a data type called `Blah`, and having defined it, you then go and say it is a member of type-class `Mult` and give it an implementation of `multiply` outside of the actual data type. The compiler finds the implementation when it wants to work with it.

Comment: @GregRos: That sounds like something I'd like to have in .NET: the ability for an interface to specify that if a type is cast to an interface it doesn't implement, the Runtime would check to see whether the interface has a metadata-specified generic class with a type parameter whose constraints would be specified by the type in question and, if so, whether that class contains all the static methods that would be necessary to build an implementation (e.g. if an interface has `void Foo(int)`, then for class `Goo` to be castable to that interface...

Comment: @supercat Having explicit interfaces that you opt into is fine, the issue is 1) not attaching them to classes and 2) not throwing away the type of the implementation. That's what I meant by a parametrized interface passed as an extra argument. E.g. `interface Num<T> { T getZero(); T add(T a, T b); }`. You can add an implementation for any class without modifying it, and can write generic math code like this: `public <T> T multiply(Num<T> typeClass, T number, int n) { // call typeClass.add(number, number) }`. Again, this falls a bit flat without higher kinds when `T` is a generic class though.

Comment: ...there should exist a method `void staticClassName<Goo>.Foo(Goo it, int p)`, and the JIT would add to the class `Goo` a method `void InterfaceName.Foo(it) { staticClassName<Goo>.Foo(this, it);}`.  Making all that work efficiently might be a little tricky, but not too bad if one is willing to accept a slowdown in the unsuccessful-cast case [and even that could probably be optimized by keeping a table of unsuccessful casts that have been attempted].

Comment: @supercat It is *not* about duck-typing.  That's a ridiculous thing to say about rigorously typesafe languages like Haskell and just shows you really haven't grokked the concept.  Higher kinded types simply provide a high level of abstraction.  As necessary, you refine the high level abstraction by adding more detail, in an interative design process.  Really, go read the linked question, go read the links they provide, maybe try out the concept in a language that supports it.  Stop throwing up reactionary insults defined by what you *are* familiar with.  That isn't how to learn.

Comment: @itsbruce: Sorry I misunderstood the concept; I was not trying to be inflammatory.  Based on what Doval says, it sounds as though what you're describing is something that I'd like to have be possible in interfaces with .NET (but which presently isn't)--basically say that for a class to be castable to an interface, either the class or the interface should have to want to allow the cast, and for each member of the interface an implementation must exist either in the class or in a spot designated by the interface.  Does that sound like what you're after?

Comment: Casting isn't an appropriate analogy. What is done with type classes (or similar constructs) is that you show how a given type satisfies the higher kinded type. This usually involves defining new functions or showing which existing functions (or methods if its an OO language like Scala) can be used.  Once this has been done, any functions defined to work with the higher type will all work with that type.  But it's much more than an interface because more than a simple set of function/method signatures are defined.  I guess I am going to have to go and write an answer to show how that works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since no one else has answered the question, I think I'll give it a go myself. I'm going to have to get a bit philosophical.

Generic programming is all about abstracting over similar types, without the loss of type information (which is what happens with object-oriented value polymorphism). In order to do this, the types must necessarily share some sort of interface (a set of operations, not the OO term) that you can use.

In object-oriented languages, types satisfy an interface by virtue of classes. Each class has its own interface, defined as part of its type. Since all classes `List<T>` share the same interface, you can write code that works no matter which `T` you choose. Another way to impose an interface is an inheritance constraint, and although the two seem different, they are sort of similar if you think about it.

In most object-oriented languages, `List<>` is not a proper type in itself. It has no methods, and thus has no interface. It is only `List<T>` that has these things. Essentially, in more technical terms, the only types you can meaningfully abstract over are those with the kind `*`. In order to make use of higher-kinded types in an object-oriented world, you have to phrase type constraints in a manner consistent with this restriction.

For example, as mentioned in the comments, we can view `Option<>` and `List<>` as "mappable", in the sense that if you have a function, you could convert an `Option<T>` into an `Option<S>`, or a `List<T>` into a `List<S>`. Remembering that classes cannot be used to abstract over higher-kinded types directly, we instead make an interface:

```
IMappable<K<_>, T> where K<T> : IMappable<K<_>, T>
```

And then we implement the interface in both `List<T>` and `Option<T>` as `IMappable<List<_>, T>` and `IMappable<Option<_>, T>` respectively. What we've done, is using higher-kinded types to place constraints on the actual (non-higher-kinded) types `Option<T>` and `List<T>`. This is how it's done in Scala, though of course Scala has features such as traits, type variables, and implicit parameters that make it more expressive.

In other languages, it is possible to abstract over higher-kinded types directly. In Haskell, one of the highest authorities on type systems, we can phrase a type class for any type, even if it has a higher kind. For example,

```
class Mappable mp where
    map :: mp a -> mp b
```

This is a constraint placed directly on an (unspecified) type `mp` which takes one type parameter, and requires it be associated with the function `map` that turns an `mp<a>` into an `mp<b>`. We can then write functions that constrain higher-kinded types by `Mappable` just like in object-oriented languages you could place an inheritance constraint. Well, sort of.

To sum things up, your ability to make use of higher-kinded types depends on your ability to constrain them or to use them as part of type constraints.

Comment: Been too busy changing jobs but finally will find some time to write my own answer.  I do think you've been distracted by the idea of constraints, though. *One* significant aspect of higher kinded types is that they allow functions/behaviour to be defined which can be applied to any type which can logically be shown to qualify.  Far from imposing constraints on existing types, type classes (one application of higher kinded types) add behaviour to them.

Comment: I think it's an issue of semantics. A type class defines a class of types. When you define a function such as `(Mappable mp) => mp a -> mp b`, you've placed a constraint on `mp` to be a member of the type class `Mappable`. When you declare a type such as `Option` to be an instance of `Mappable`, you add behavior to that type. I guess you could make use of that behavior locally without ever constraining any type, but then it's no different from defining an ordinary function.

Comment: Also, I am quite certain type classes aren't directly related to higher-kinded types. Scala has higher-kinded types, but not type classes, and you could restrict type classes to types with the kind `*` without making them unusable. It's definitely true that type classes are very powerful when working with higher-kinded types, though.

Comment: Scala has type classes. They are implemented with implicits. The implicits provide the equivalent of the Haskell type class instances.  It's a more fragile implementation than Haskell's because there is no dedicated syntax for it.  But it was always one of the key purposes of Scala implicits and they do the job.